# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' even with latest build tools

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-resources

I am getting this error when I try to run my project. I have installed the latest build tools- 23.0.3 but still the error persists. How do I fix this?

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Ishmita\\Documents\\GitHub\\FurAlert-Native-Build\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":3}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Ishmita\\Documents\\GitHub\\FurAlert-Native-Build\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-v23\\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":32}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ishmita\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.901 secs

[SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjaAU.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 in your module's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: didn't fixed my same issue

Comment: why is that, can you please explain?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal: IIRC, `android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse` was only added in API Level 23. Attempts to reference it with a `compileSdkVersion` below 23 will fail.

Comment: i have it as 25 and buildtoolversion - 25.0.0. Rather than downgrading, is there any other way to do it sir?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal: I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain, **in detail**, what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i was able to correct the error by initiating a gradle stack trace command through the terminal which exactly pointed to the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 27):

Issue **SOLVED** by making **library** and **app** *build.gradle* same ... compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion.

library **build.gradle** and

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    .....
    .....
}
```

app **build.gradle**

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jazzbpn . I was using Ionic and having this issue. I managed to fix this problem by changing target=android-25 in platforms/android/CordovaLIb/project.properties

Answer (score 8):

Error:Execution failed for task com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:

> finished with non-zero exit value 1

One reason for this error to occure is that the file path to a resource file is to long:

```
Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters
```

Fix: Move your project folder closer to the root of your disk

**Don't**:// folder/folder/folder/folder/very_long_folder_name/MyProject...

**Do**://folder/short_name/MyProject

---

Another reason could be duplicated resources or name spaces

Example:

```
  <style name="MyButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent_color</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

---

And make sure all file names and extensions are in lowercase

**Wrong**

```
myimage.PNG
myImage.png
```

**Correct**

```
my_image.png
```

---

Make sure to Clean/Rebuild project

(delete the 'build' folder)

Answer (score 4):

I stucked for two days and finally found my solution. I changed the compileSdkVersion to 27 (same with buildToolsVersion)

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Comment: where is that build tools version i cant find it anywhere

Answer (score 3):

as a quick fix to this question, make sure your compile Sdk verion, your buildtoolsversion, your appcompat, and finally your support library are all running on the same sdk version, for further clarity take a look at the image i just uploaded. Cheers. Follow the red annotations and get rid of that trouble.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason

```
resConfigs "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
```

can be source of this issue

Answer (score 1):

this issue comes up with 2 reasons

1) the android SDK has not been install
2) the build toold version corresponsind to the android SDK is not installed

to start
open terminal and type `android` and install API 26(updated one) and build tools version 26.0.1 or 26.0.2
then try to run using command ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that sometimes android studio loses track of the resources file and can't build on launch. If the above answers are to no avail, try

```
Build => Rebuild Project
```

I lost many hours to this when I was a beginner at Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `target=android-26` to `target=android-23`

> project.properties

this works great for me.

Comment: where is this file located?

Answer (score 0):

After updating my Android SDK I stumbled upon this very problem and I tried many ways without success. What was most irritating to me when searching for a fix, were the lots of answers suggesting to change the **CompileSdkVersion** to a certain number while obviously this number changes with time, so here's what I did instead.

I created a new project and ran it on the emulator to make sure it's working, then checked its "*\android\app\build.gradle*" file and copied the numeric value of **CompileSdkVersion** and pasted into the same file in my other project that could not be built properly anymore. Now my problem's gone. Hope that helps.