# i am trying to run my app I am getting the following error:

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Mohamed Sallam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: try restart Android Studio, Clean Build and Rebuild.

Comment: i do .but no change

Answer (score 0):

there may be problem in gradle file config
check for compilesdk version that match all dependencies and build tools
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237132/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-even-with-latest-build-to)