# Using build tools 19, should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I go to android studios and try to run a program it says:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Change the build tools version to latest one from build.gradle file

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237132/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-even-with-latest-build-to) question should help you out.

Comment: @Afterfield No... That error is completely different. Actually read the reason, not the exception

Answer (score 0):

Its showing the error right ... open build.gradle file and change the build-tools version to 21... and then Build > Clean Project...