# Issues while importing CSipSimple library as a module

Tags: android, csip-simple

I am trying to import the cSipSimple library in my project for sip functionalities and while trying to import the file,  I did the usual way of importing i.e:

```
Add as a new module
add in gradle (Compile project)
Removed App ID  from lib gradle and added replace icon etc in app Manifest.
```

Still while syncing the gradle, I am again getting a list of errors:

```
    Error:(552) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(397) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(622) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(539) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(629) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(545) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(644) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(646) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(577) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(646) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(576) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(576) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(552) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(397) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(622) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(629) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(539) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(545) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(644) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(577) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:(576) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(646) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(576) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(646) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
```

This is the first time I am trying to import a project and use in as a module. So unable to findout the exact issue. If I am missing out something, please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try Invalidate Caches/Restart? whenever we add new module or add any dependency build folder again while compile. so try this. hope it will help you.

Comment: @HemantParmar: Thank you. Let me try

Comment: Its not working out

Comment: ok have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237132/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-even-with-latest-build-to/41520281) & [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/build-failed-appprocessdebugresources-failed)

Answer (score 0):

You must exclude incompatible types modules (like your module having attribute attribute parameter here)

**A example below**

**Error**: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined

**Solution**:
You must exclude `appcompat-v7` from material-dialog:

```
compile ("com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0"){
exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/184