# How to install React Native Maps in React Native?

Tags: gradle, react-native, react-native-maps

I am beginner in `react-native` and trying to install `react-native-maps` in my `react-native` android app by following [this](https://dev.to/droidmakk/react-native-maps-done-right-for-android-d3o) tutorial.

After making all changes, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237132/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-even-with-latest-build-to/41520281), I am getting following error:-

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

Complete Traceback is as follows:-

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/vineet/test/maps4/node_modules (9ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Configure project :app 
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 23 in /home/vineet/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 23 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 23 (revision: 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 23 (revision: 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 23 in /home/vineet/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23
"Install Android SDK Platform 23 (revision: 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 23 (revision: 3)" finished.
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.

> Configure project :react-native-maps 
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

/home/vineet/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/33cf2996857d19942091152cf6b82923/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/home/vineet/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/33cf2996857d19942091152cf6b82923/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/home/vineet/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/33cf2996857d19942091152cf6b82923/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
/home/vineet/test/maps4/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/home/vineet/test/maps4/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/home/vineet/test/maps4/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
error: failed linking references.


> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:314)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 123 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Following are the changes in files:-
**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maps4"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "maps4",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    supportLibVersion = "25.0.1"
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'maps4'

include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')

include ':app'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.maps4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY"
      />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.maps4;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new MapsPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I have tried many times to install `react-native-maps` but couldn't. Are there any other library for `react-native` to include maps?

Comment: Why do you not use the newest version of React Native?

Comment: I tried to follow installation instructions for newer version given in docs but it gave bugs.

Comment: What're bugs you faced?

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

Comment: Try to create a new project `react-native int myApp` after that run it in your simulator it should work without issues, after that try to install react-native-maps and follow the installation guide

Comment: ok. will try with simulator

Comment: I tried to run ```react-native-0.56``` on simulator in linux but could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I can see from your package json you are using an old version of both react-native and react-native-maps

```
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-maps": "0.21.0"
```

I suggest you to update to the latest ones if possible.

I'm using **react-native 0.60.5** and **react-native-maps 0.25.0** in production with **AndroidX** support.

*gradle.properties*

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If you cannot update I suggest you to open the project with Android Studio and check with gradle sync if there are any suggestions from the IDE.

Since in `react-native-0.60` and higher, there is autolinking, therefore you need not to run `react-native link <package-name>` command. After following installation documentation for all versions section, if your app crashs when you try to open it, then add following line in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xmml`:-

```
<uses-library
                android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
                android:required="false" />
```

For more information on crash issue, you can check [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2880) out.

Answer (score 0):

android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored was added in API 24 so you can't use it with version 23. You can use a style that was added before version 23.

```
// android/build.gradle inside allprojects { 
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion = 27
                    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still it gives error ```Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.```

Comment: Please share your build.gradle with updated sub-projects